# Remove spacing between certain items of ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, spacing

I have a custom adapter, which uses a Cursor as data input.
Now I filter certain entries in order to not display them, because I think it´s the best way in my case.

I basically make them disappear by setting the layout Visibility to GONE, but anyway, the spaces between the items stay there, which means if I filter out 10 sequenced items, I have a gap of 10 * space-height between the prior one and the following behind.

In my case, it´s useless to set the spacing via xml, which seem to be possible as I read. I could only set the spacing to zero, which is not my actually intent.

How could I remove a single spacing or make it invisible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Just remove the general ListView spacing and add it as margin to each row. That way, if the row view is gone, the spacing is as well.

Comment: Unsurpricingly. I have changed my system.Now I pre-filter my entries and use an ArrayAdapter with custom container classes, so I do not need to filter my entries in the adapter itself. thank you anyway :)

Comment: That is the better solution anyways than setting rows to gone. :-)